# Using core validation within custom validation on CakePHP Forms/Models?

Tags: php, cakephp, validation

#### Using CakePHP 1.3

I understand the example at http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1143/Data-Validation#Adding-your-own-Validation-Methods-1181 on how to add my own validation methods, but maybe I'm missing something.

I only want to validate that Field_B is 'numeric' (a core validation) **if** Field_A (a select/option) is equal to a certain value.

It seems that I'm supposed to add a custom validation, and then I check the values of other fields with `$this->data`, but **how do I call on a built-in validation from within a custom validation function?** Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Validation::numeric($this->data['field'])`

Validation class (validation.php) is located in `cake/cake/libs` and you can see the available methods by inspecting the file (they're the same as the ones you pass to the validation array).

Validation methods return true if validation passes.

Comment: So, is `Validation` available in the model scope, or do I need to include it before using it?

Comment: `Validation` is imported whenever the Model base class file is included so it will always be available in any of your models. You can call the method statically, or get an instance `$val = Validation::getInstance(); $val->numeric($this->data['field']);`